# NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can import `selenium` with no issues, however the `webdriver` module import gives me a hard time as it can't be located. The `selenium` is definitely installed properly, and my python can find it:

```
print("Selenium package is located at:", selenium.__file__)
```

console output:

```
C:\Users\\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\__init__.py
```

But upon trying to find the `webdriver`:

```
print("webdriver selenium module is located at:", webdriver.__file__)
```

Console output: `NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined`

my Chrome version is: Version 121.0.6167.140 (Official Build) (32-bit), but I can't locate the chromedriver.exe file on my computer.

Comment: I think you may need download the driver from https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/ to your PC and set it to the PATH.

Comment: Did you import webdriver separately. Only by using `import selenium` or `from selenium import * ` wont import the webdriver. So you should use `from selenium import webdriver`

Answer (score 0):

Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser. Since you're using Chrome, you can download the relevant driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.

> If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, please consult the [Chrome for Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) availability dashboard. This page provides convenient [JSON endpoints](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json) for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.

Lastly, note that selenium package [Requires: Python >=3.8](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#:%7E:text=Requires%3A%20Python%20%3E%3D3.8).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the chromedriver.exe, you need to download it.
Ensure that the version of chromedriver matches the version of Chrome you're using (121.0.6167.140).
Once downloaded, you either need to add it in your system's PATH (Important)
For the import use, **from selenium import webdriver**